# Assembly - How 0x80 with ecx=esp work?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have the next code:

```
Doit: mov eax, 4 ; for write system call
      push Dword, 0x44434241
      mov ebx, 1
      mov ecx, esp
      mov edx, 4
      int 0x80
      add esp, 4
      ret
```

As I check, It's print "ABCD", but why? AS I understood it, on the stack we have the next picture:

Low --- `0x41  0x42  0x43  0x44` -- esp,

i.e esp is point to 0x44. When we call  0x80. it should print "DCBA". What I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stack picture is wrong. Because x86 is a little-endian architecture, ESP is equal to the address of the least-significant byte in the pushed value, or `0x41`.

From [Intel's priceless Architecture Developer's Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.html):

> When an item is pushed onto the stack, the processor decrements the
>   ESP register, then writes the item at the new top of stack.

Comment: So as I understood, we dec esp, and then push.. i.e the push instruction's start point would be esp, and for that we will get the next picture: esp -- 0x41 0x42 0x43 0x44 -- (esp before the push was taken).

Comment: This has nothing to do with the stack setup. Simply push the value: 0x41424344 for correct little-endian storage.

Comment: @BrettHale: You're right, I was trying to address the diagram showing "Low" and "esp" incorrectly, and apparently confused myself in the process. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issue. You are simply pushing a 32-bit value onto the stack, which will be at the address ESP. x86 is little-endian, and stores the least-significant byte first:

ESP + 0 (0x41), ESP + 1 (0x42), ESP + 2 (0x43), ESP + 3 (0x44). When accessed as an array of bytes however, it *starts* at ESP and increments through memory.

There's **nothing** wrong with your use of the stack, it's just misunderstanding of word / dword / qword storage vs. byte access.